# Parent to vertex, object change position when applying skin modifier

Tags: modifiers, vertices, parent, soft-body

I have a little problem whith vertex parent. I'm working on a softbody cable, and i need to have a simple on/off switch attached to it. Everything is fine, until i apply the skin modifier.
Make a cable (multiple vertex) and add softbody. Without skin modifier i add an empty and vertex parent to three vertex on the cable. Start the animation and everything works great. the empty follow the cable.
As soon as i enable skin modifier (to solidify the cable), the empty immediatly offset to new position. I try applying scale, rotation ecc...
the only difference i notice is that mark root some vertices in the skin modifier change the empty position to another location.

I will post the blend file example. Try to switch skin modifier on/off and start the animation to see the different results.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/QwD5gvMq/

Comment: Skin modifiers do not generate a consistent number of vertices, so vertex parenting from live skin modifiers will often break-- the vertex considered to be the parent keeps changing.  I would recommend trying to do the same thing with a curve object instead of a skin modified mesh object, which will allow you to use a follow path or clamp to constraint to acquire the proper position along the cable instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I started using the curve but it doesn't retain the shape, it tends to stretch too much if i move one of the hooks. Any other ideas using mesh? Or maybe a solution to avoid curve stretching... Thanks again!

Comment: There are a number of alternatives.  The simplest is just to apply you skin modifier rather than leaving it live.  Another is to create vertex groups and then use constraints that target the vertex group to acquire loc, rot, scale from the proper point of the mesh instead.  I'm sure there are more alternatives as well.